# iterate over array of json with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object

I know this may seem basic to some of you, but I am trying to iterate a json object with jquery, how to reach to each webpage name of each producer. Please help! 
on the bottom is my code any help is welcome.

```
{
    "producers": [
        {
            "producer": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Radosa",
                "address": " Grenvägen 1-3",
                "zipcode": " 577 39",
                "district": " Hultsfred",
                "webpage": [
                    {
                        "name": "waste",
                        "purpose": "sample "
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Ultra Worker",
                        "purpose": "Posao"
                    }
                ],
                "logoURL": "../producenter/images/ema.png",
                "latitude": "57.4999",
                "longitude": "15.828"
            }
        },
        {
            "producer": {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Marko",
                "address": " Grenvägen 1-3",
                "zipcode": " 577 39",
                "district": " Hultsfred",
                "webpage": [
                    {
                        "name": "Sample name",
                        "purpose": "sample purpose"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Sample name",
                        "purpose": "sample purpose"
                    }
                ],
                "logoURL": "../producenter/images/ema.png",
                "latitude": "57.4999",
                "longitude": "15.828"
            }
        }
    ]
}


$.each(data.producers, function(key, value) {
        console.log(value.producer); ------ this works,
        console.log(value.webpage.name); ------ this don't work. How to reach this value?
    });
```

Comment: Reach each webpage name? But each producer has more than one webpage.

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(value.webpage.name);
```

should be

```
// webpage is an array too, get the first element of it for example
console.log(value.producer.webpage[0].name);
```

Answer (score 1):

say your json object is data

try this

```
 $.each(data.producers,function(i,v){
     $.each(v.producer.webpage,function(i1,v1){ //<--since webpage is an array, use each again...
         alert(v1.name);
     })
 });
```

or simply you can use index..

```
 $.each(data.producers,function(index,value){
    console.log(value.producer.webpage[0].name); //first name
     console.log(value.producer.webpage[0].name); //second name
 });
```

Comment: $.each(data.producers,function(i,v){
     $.each(v.producer.webpage,function(i1,v1){ //<--since webpage is an array, use each again...
         alert(v1.name);
     })
 });

This works for me, thanks :)

Comment: welcome.. if this helped you then you can accept this as answer so that other user having the same problem as yours can try it out in future.. anyways glad it helped.. happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Since `value.producer.webpage` is an `array` you need to:

```
for(var i=0; i<value.producer.webpage.length; i++) {
   var webpage = value.producer.webpage[i];
   console.log(webpage.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sou can do that like this:

```
for(var producer in Object.producers){
    if(Object.producers.hasOwnProperty(producer)  && Object.producers[producer].webpage!==undefined){
        for(var i=0; i<Object.producers[producer].webpage.length; i+=1){
          // Your further code here
        }
    }
}
```